# Mongoose-Mongo {[CastError: Cast to Object failed for value "..." at path "..."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm have this error:

```
{ [ValidationError: Contact validation failed]
  message: 'Contact validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { Contact: 
      { [CastError: Cast to Object failed for value "ContactExample" at path "Contact"]
        message: 'Cast to Object failed for value "ContactExample" at path "Contact"',
        name: 'CastError',
        kind: 'Object',
        value: 'ContactExample',
        path: 'Contact',
        reason: undefined },
}
Same for ContactType
```

My code is the following:

ContactSchema.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Contact = new Schema({
    Contact: {Type: String},
    ContactType: {Type: String}, 
    ContactOwner: {type: String} 

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Contact", Contact);
```

Route:

```
app.post('/newcontact', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    ContactModel.count({"Contact": req.body.Contact}, function(err, result){
        if (result>0) res.send('Contact already taken');
        else{
            var newContact = new ContactModel();   
            console.log(req.body);
            newContact.ContactOwner = req.user.email;
            newContact.Contact = req.body.Contact;
            newContact.ContactType = req.body.ContactType;
            newContact.save(function(err){console.log(err);});
            res.send('Done');
        }
    });
});
```

I tried filling the field "_id" and also doing ContactModel(ContactOwner: ......) but it still gives me that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of `type` in your schema incorrect please replace schema definition as

```
var Contact = new Schema({
    Contact: {type: String},
    ContactType: {type: String}, 
    ContactOwner: {type: String} 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel so stupid now, I was too focused over route's code instead of schema